# C# Custom Iterator Implementation

Tags: operator-keyword, keyword, c#-2.0

I have a class, say Myclass, with a list variable, say string list, which I want to call from outside Myclass object instance, in a loop, succinctly like:

```
Myclass myclass = new Myclass();

foreach (string s in myclass)
{
}
```

I suspect it uses the implicit operator keyword inside of Myclass on a property. Syntax grrr..!  Any help?

(Not sure if it's good practice but there are times when it comes in handy).

Comment: The class can not assume to have properties and behavior of the types of it's properties. That's why instance of MyClass can not be iterated as it's property. You need to implement IEnumerable interface in the class and implement its methods which will deal with the list property internally.

Comment: Seems I was way off on this. And of course the answer makes perfect sense to me now that I know it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Foreach basically works on sequence. Your `MyClass` need to implement IEnumerable and eventually return IEnumerator implementation via GetEnumerator.

IEnumerator basically provides MoveNext and Current property which your foreach loop uses to query sequence elements one after another.

You can get more info around this by searching around Iterators in C#. Adding short snippet so you can visualize what i meant :

```
 public class MyIterator : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string> { "hi", "hello" };
        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach(var item in lst)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Consumer
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            foreach(var item in new MyIterator())
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for the extra effort of writing sample code. It always helps. Cheers!